# PowerPivot Error Message

Tags: excel, powerpivot

PowerPivot was working fine for me last night. This morning, when I open my workbook, PowerPivot simply won't launch. The button is not grayed out, but when I click it, nothing happens.

Clicking on any of my PivotCharts produces a field list like it should, but it tells me that I should "Refresh" my data. I hit refresh, and get the error message:

```
Embedded Analysis Services Engine: Could not load embedded PowerPivot Data.
```

Every once in a while after this error message, I get another telling me that my Powerpivot data is corrupt, and I have the option to do nothing or attempt to recover it. When I attempt to recover it, it tells me that the data recovery has been `successful`, but all of my charts and pivottables are now wiped clean of data, and Powerpivot still will not launch.

I've tried Googling this and looking at the solutions online. I'm already an administrator on my computer. I've tried rebooting and re-installing PowerPivot. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of windows do you have? XP? Did you notice at the bottom of the following page that the way you get the privs is different depending on the version of Windows? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/as_emea/archive/2012/04/27/non-admin-users-not-able-to-use-powerpivot-for-excel-2012-on-windows-xp.aspx

Comment: @Jim I am using Windows 7, and Excel 2010 and PowerPivot for Excel 2010 downloaded from the microsoft site. I am also an admin on my computer. Any ideas?

Comment: In the past I have had a terrible time making sure that I had the correct privs in Windows 7.  I do not want to sound dumb but are you sure you have the needed privs?

Comment: @Jim If I am an admin already, how would I go about checking what privs I already have and which ones I need?

Comment: Are you able to change your rights or the rights of another user?

Comment: This  is better: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-do-you-set-yourself-up-as-the-administrator-in/eddfcdc1-d024-446f-ab8c-a5f1ae0ddf43

Comment: @Jim I am an administrator but as this is a work laptop I can't change the rights of any other user. I can't change my rights either. Not sure where to go from here :/

Comment: Again...  I do not mean to sound stupid   :-)   but why do you think you have admin privs?

Comment: @Jim Don't worry about offending me at all, I'm just grateful for the help! If I go to Control Panel > Users > Change User Type, I can see a list of all the users on the computer. My user name is listed as an Administrator under "Type". A couple other are as well, but most are just listed as "users." Does that help?

Comment: Although that might be correct, Windows 7 uses UAC (user Account Control).   So, you should look there to be sure...  The link to the documentation is below...  (BTW, I know of a Windows XP machine that has Admin for the type but the machine account is definately not a typical Admin user) The UAC link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731416(WS.10).aspx

Comment: @Jim - I followed that article and turned off UAC, and PowerPivot works! Huzzah! Thank you so much!

Comment: I will post it as an answer.  Could you accept it as the answer by clicking the downward facing green arrow and then clicking the up arrow for if the answer was extra usefu?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the instructions at the fowllowing website to turn off the UAC in Windows 7.  That will allow PowerPivot  to work. The link is  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731416(WS.10).aspx

Jim

Comment: Could you accept this as the answer by clicking the downward facing green arrow on the top left of this article and then clicking the up arrow for (just above the other arrow) if the answer was extra usefu? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, just saw this! Done! Thanks again for the help Jim!